# Is there API for Esri Story Maps?

Tags: web-mapping, story-map

I want to create an Esri Story Map and integrate/include an own web map. I would prefer to create both the web map and story map using an API so that I can programmatically develop the maps.

Is there an API for Esri Story Maps and is it the same as for creating web maps (there it is the ArcGIS API for Javascript)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be covered in the [Story Maps Frequently Asked Questions](https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/faq/):

> While most story maps are created using one of the Story Map app
>   templates we provide, story maps can also be created from scratch by
>   developers using the developer APIs and tools in ArcGIS for
>   Developers.